# Request Capture like requestbin PHP

Tags: php, http, request, httprequest

**Background:**
I am working with an api and stuck on webhooks. The api sends a http post request to a url of my choosing on triggering an event. I used request bin and ensured that api is sending data. But i can't find a way to implement this functionality on my side.

**Problem:**
Need to capture http request like request bin and store the payload that my api is sending.

**Reference from api documentation:**
Payload
When an event happens and triggers a webhook, we’ll send a POST request to a URL of your choosing. The POST request will be in the UTF-8 charset, and application/x-www-form-urlencoded encoding. The POST body will include a field named payload. This field contains a JSON encoded object with details of the object that caused the hooked event.

**I have seen other answers, but i can't find what i exactly want to do. Any help would be appreciated, i am stuck on this since 4 days.**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You guys might think i am an idiot. But the issue was i was giving my localhost url to api for sending the payload. The reason i was giving my localhost url was that all the curl calls were working fine and i was able to post and get required data. The moment i put my code on an online server all the three ways i was using worked.

1. Use **$_POST**.
2. Use **$_REQUEST**.
3. Use **file_get_contents("php://input")**

Hope this helps someone.